# How to two-way binding parent node and look up it's child master data using angularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Data

```
{
 folders: {
  id123: {
   authorizedUsers: {
    u123: true,
    u456: true
   }
  }
 },
 users: {
  u123: { name: 'David' },
  u456: { name: 'Ali' }
 }
}
```

With above data, I can use

`$folder = $firebase(fbRef.child('folders').child('/id123'))` to kept sync the data.

Since the new angularFire ($firebase) take only 1 argument (ref), how to use callback to get the `authorizedUsers key` and retrieve the related master data in `users` node?

Below is the method i use without $firebase but no idea how to use pure firebase api in conjunction with $firebase

```
$scope.authorizedUsers = [];
fbRef.child('folders/').child($routeParams.folderID).on('child_added', function(ss) {
  fbRef.child('users/').child(childSnapshot.name()).once('value',function(user) {
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.authorizedUsers.push(user.val());
      console.log($scope.authorizedUsers);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the .$on('loaded') event to find out when the data has been loaded, and then create a new $firebase reference to fetch the other records. For example:

```
var folder = $firebase(fbRef.child('folder').child('id123'));
folder.$on('loaded', function(data) {
  var users = data['authorizedUsers'];
  for (var user in users) {
    $firebase(fbRef.child('users').child(user)).$on('loaded', function(userData) {
      $scope.authorizedUsers.push(userData);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: $on loaded not reload the data when using $location to switch. How to deal with this?